# bing speech to text error in Android

Tags: android, speech-to-text, bing, speech, azure-cognitive-services

I have gone through documentation of bing speech to text api, i implemented a simple app which just starts speech to text on button click. I have hard coded the key values provided in Cognitive Services console. Now when I start the function as shown in sample app it throws following error. I have searched on google but i can not trace the root of the issue.

```
    09-16 11:39:09.799 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : originating error 0x80070057
    09-16 11:39:09.809 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : Application Name:
    09-16 11:39:09.819 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : originating error 0x80070057
    09-16 11:39:09.819 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : originating error 0x80070057
    09-16 11:39:09.819  3676  4433 D EnterpriseController: netId is 0
    09-16 11:39:09.819  3676  4433 D Netd    : getNetworkForDns: using netid 0 for uid 10068
    09-16 11:39:09.824 25615 26122 I NLPLAT  : originating error 0x8e200005
    09-16 11:39:09.824 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : Refreshing token S
    09-16 11:39:09.824  3676  4433 D EnterpriseController: netId is 0
    09-16 11:39:09.824  3676  4433 D Netd    : getNetworkForDns: using netid 0 for uid 10068
    09-16 11:39:09.829 25615 26124 I NLPLAT  : originating error 0x8e200005
    09-16 11:39:09.829 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : Initializing Audio Services
    09-16 11:39:09.829 25615 25655 W libOpenSLES: class OutputMix interface 0 requested but unavailable MPH=43
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 W AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 1, track 16000 Hz, output 48000 Hz
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : Initializing Speech Services
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : No application id provided to controller
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : GetIdentityPropertyValue 3
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : Useragent Value Android Assistant (Android; Unknown;Unknown;ProcessName/AppName=Unknown;DeviceType=Near;SpeechClient=1.0.160511)
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : Url: 'https://websockets.platform.bing.com/ws/speech/recognize/continuous'
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : Locale: 'en-us'
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : Application Id: ''
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : Version: 4.0.150429
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : UserAuthorizationToken:
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : ServerLoggingLevel: 1
    09-16 11:39:09.834 25615 25655 I NLPLAT  : Initiating websocket connection. m_connection=0x0 host=websockets.platform.bing.com port=443
```

Bing OnError function says :

```
NameNotFound -1910505467
```

Comment: After searching for a while, changed targetSDKVersion to 22 from 23 and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue because of network connection.Check your network connection before calling "this.micClient.startMicAndRecognition();" like

```
 if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                this.micClient.startMicAndRecognition();
            }else{
                Log.i("Error","No network available");
            }

 public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```